# What does the bars above the health bar mean?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

After drinking an energy drink, there are little yellow and white bars above the health bar. What are those? What do they represent?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The bars over top of your health bar shows the current boost level from using consumables. Each bar corresponds to a different level of boost:

- **Level 1**:+1% Health Regen per 8 Seconds
- **Level 2**:+2% Health Regen per 8 Seconds
- **Level 3**:+3% Health Regen per 8 Seconds and +2.5% Movement Speed Bonus
- **Level 4**:+4% Health Regen per 8 Seconds and +6.2% Movement Speed Bonus

You can increase the your boost level by using the following consumables
(see image below for more detail):

- **Energy Drinks**: 1.5 bars of boost (40% of total boost)
- **Pain killer**: 2 bars of boost (60% of total boost)
- **Adrenaline Shot**: 4 bars of boost (100% of total boost)

One thing to keep in mind is that the effects of using the consumables is cumulative, so drinking two energy drinks will get you to around 80% of your boost bar (slightly less, as the bar degrades while you drink the second energy drink).

[image: More detail on boosts]
[Boost amount source](https://forums.tiny-spaceship.com/t/playerunknowns-battlegrounds-an-ocd-thread/25?u=magnumdopus)

Answer (score 2):

They are [boosts](https://forums.playbattlegrounds.com/topic/652-make-use-of-energy-drinks-and-pain-killers-updated/). They come from both energy drinks and painkillers.

First 2 bars (the leftmost) are slight health improvements, meaning they can slowly heal you until the bar decays. You get faster health regeneration in the second bar.  The third bar is a speed boost, meaning you run and move slightly faster. The fourth is even more speed increase and health regeneration.

Good luck! Get those chicken dinners!